# Why is the output of this code implementation defined?

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the following two function overloads:

```
int foo(int a)
{
  return 20;
}

const char foo(double b)
{
  return -3;
}

int x = foo(6.0);
cout << x;
```

Why does the result of this example depend on the concrete compiler or platform?

Compilation is by ISO/IEC 14882:1998.

Comment: What do you mean?  `foo(6.0)` should always give you `-3`.  Do you see it as 253 sometimes?

Comment: What output do you see, or is this a quiz -like problem?

Comment: Side note: returning anything *by value* as const is (nearly?) meaningless, the value would have to be copied anyway... At very best, it prevents some optimisations otherwise possible (e. g. calling move instead of copy constructor)...

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed. The (GCC) compiler ignores the const qualifier.

Comment: @SergeyA Why are quiz questions not legitimate SO questions per se?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function overloading is a red herring; the overload `char foo(double)` will be picked on all platforms.

The key difference is in the type `char` itself: the standard allows it to be either signed or unsigned. Which one is chosen is implementation defined.

On systems with unsigned `char`, the function would thus return the positive number `CHAR_MAX - 2` (as the result of `char(-3)`).

Comment: Also you could put this to the test by having both functions take a double. It should give an error that it can't determine the function based on return type alone. And by test I mean that it selects the function based on arguments.